# Opening a new php page using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, html-select

I would like to open a new page whenever a user clicks one of my html select options using JQuery. Following the example on the JQuery tutorial, I structured my code as shown below. However, the page doesn't open when I click any of the options

```
$('#Databases').change(function () {

    $.post("test.php");
});
```

Where `Databases` is my selectID. Why can't I open `test.php` ? Is there a solution?

Comment: `$.post()` makes an AJAX request. If you want to change the current page you need to [set `window.location` as appropriate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either use `window.location` or `window.open`:

```
$('#Databases').change(function (e) {
        window.open("testScript.php"); // if you want to open another window
        // window.location.href = "testScript.php"; //if you want to open in same window
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The `open()` method opens a new browser window.
If you want to open new page in same browser window I would suggest to use `window.location.assign()`.

Example :

```
$('#Databases').change(function () {
   window.location.assign("test.php");
});
```

**[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)**

Answer (score 1):

Use window.open function:

```
$('#Databases').change(function () {
    window.open("test.php");
});
```

Because `$.post` is just `$.ajax` with `type='post'` - asynchronous call. You can open new window in `done` or `success` section of that function, but I guess that is not what you wanted.